# Arduino SD card read last line

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to display text in a file stored in a SD card.
I can read the first line up to the 2nd to the last line. However, when I try to read the last line the program stops running and the LCD displays all white squares. What am I doing wrong here?

```
myFile.seek(0);
char cr;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 15;){
cr = myFile.read();
    if(cr == '\n')
    {
        i++;
    }
}
while(true){
    cr = myFile.read();
    if((cr == '\n')||(cr == '\r'))
        break;
    lcd.print(cr);
}
```

This is the file's content:

```
1. 00.1
2. SUN
3. 00.00.0001
4. 00:00:01
5. 00.2
6. MON
7. 00.00.0002
8. 00:00:02
9. 00.3
10. WED
11. 00.00.0003
12. 00:00:03
13. 00.4
14. THU
15. 00.00.0004
16. 00:00:04
```

Comment: looks like this code reads 15 lines, then reads a 16 and writes it to the lcd. Since we don't know what is on that 16th line it's going to be hard to help you. I don't see anything obviously fatal in there, but you really should check the reads for success so you'll know yo at least read something and read up on `std::getline`.

Comment: correct me if im wrong. there are 16 lines written inside the file. from line 0 to line 15 that makes 16 lines overall right?

Comment: so lets say the last line is written "20". 20 will be the 16th line or line number 15?? am I right?

Comment: @bembe24 why are you asking us what is on line *15* or *16*? It's you who is supposed to **edit** your post and add the content of the file in it, otherwise we cannot **magically** guess what is supposed to be printed on the *LCD* solely on the base of the code that reads data. *e.g. if the file has empty lines, it's perfectly normal to see nothing; if the file has corrupted data, it's perfectly normal to see weird characters on screen; and so on*

Comment: im sorry im new to this. Ill try to edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
  while(true){
      cr = myFile.read();
      if((cr == '\n')||(cr == '\r'))
          break;
      lcd.print(cr);
  }
```

you have some code that is supposed to read, and print, all characters on the 16th line of your file, and **stop** when a *newline* character is found.

It looks acceptable, but **what if** the *16th line* is **not terminated** by `\n` or `\r` ?

The [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) of `read()` says that this function returns `-1` if there is no data available. Clearly, if the file ends without a *newline*, that is precisely what is going to happen. So now you are **stuck** in a loop in which you read `-1` endlessly, but why do you see those *white blocks* on screen?

Let's see. `lcd.print(char)` is inherited from `class Print`, and it [contains](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.cpp) the following code:

```
size_t Print::print(char c)
{
  return write(c);
}
```

inside [`Print.h`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h), `Print::write(uint8_t)` is declared to be a **purely virtual method**, which means that its implementation can be found in one of its sub-classes, in this case [`LiquidCrystal.cpp`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/LiquidCrystal/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp):

```
inline size_t LiquidCrystal::write(uint8_t value) {
  send(value, HIGH);
  return 1; // assume sucess
}
```

Now, we find out that the original `-1` of type `char`, which is encoded as `0xFF`, is interpreted as `255` of type `uint8_t`. A quick look at the following table

[image]

reveals that 255 (last column, last row) corresponds to a full black square.

Ok, we are almost there, only that you see *white squares* rather than *black squares*. On this regard, it should be noted that your code is *continuosly*, and without **any delay**, printing stuff on the *lcd*. So it is likely that the *lcd screen* keeps being **refreshed** *(and its content possibly shifted?)*, thus making the *black blocks* appear *whiter* than they truly are.

---

**TL;DR Solution:**

```
  while(true){
      cr = myFile.read();
      if((cr == '\n')||(cr == '\r') || (cr < 0))
          break;
      lcd.print(cr);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! IT worked!! I was still confused how '\n' and '\r' was used in the code.